# Why is the Cauchy product of two convergent (but not absolutely) series either convergent or indeterminate (but does not converge to infinity)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is well-known that

> the *Cauchy product* of two *absolutely* convergent series is *absolutely*
>   convergent.

However, my professor added (without giving a proof) that **if the series are convergent (but not absolutely convergent), then the Cauchy product is either convergent or irregular** (i.e. *indeterminate*), but **not divergent to infinity**.

How do you prove this statement?

Comment: You are asking a good question, but not asking nicely... I will use this comment as a replacement for the upvote for question.

Answer (score 6):

We can use [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem) for the proof. Suppose the two series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ are condtionally but not absolutely convergent. For $\lvert x\rvert < 1$, we define

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\quad \text{and}\quad g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n.$$

By Abel's theorem, we have

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) = \underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n}_A\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to 1^-} g(x) = \underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n}_B,$$

and therefore, with $h(x) = f(x)\cdot g(x)$,

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} h(x) = A\cdot B.$$

The coefficients in the Power series expansion of $h$ are the terms of the Cauchy product of the two series,

$$h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n, ~ \text{ where } c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}.$$

We denote the partial sums of $\sum c_n$ by $s_n$, and define

$$H(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n x^n.$$

Assuming that we had $s_n \to +\infty$, for every $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$, there is an $N_M$ such that $s_n \geqslant M$ for all $n \geqslant N_M$. Then for $0 < x < 1$ we have

$$H(x) = \sum_{n < N_M} s_nx^n + \sum_{n=N_M}^\infty s_n x^n \geqslant \sum_{n < N_M} s_n x^n + \frac{x^{N_M}\cdot M}{1-x},$$

and hence

$$\liminf_{x\to 1^-} (1-x)H(x) \geqslant M.$$

But - setting $s_{-1} = 0$ - we have

$$h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (s_n -s_{n-1}) x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n x^n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_{n-1}x^n = (1-x)H(x),$$

and so the assumption $s_n \to +\infty$ contradicts the fact that

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} h(x) = A\cdot B.$$