# Problem with reading a proof: uniqueness of integer solution to $0<(za-1)a^{q-1}<1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, integers

> If $m,n\in\mathbb N, m<n, z=\frac{m}{n}, q\ge 2$, the inequality $0<(za-1)a^{q-1}<1$ has solution $a\in\mathbb N$.
>   
> Then the solution to the inequality above is unique.

The question is simple: how to prove the statement above?

I am currently studying

> Daniel D. Bonar & Michael Khoury Jr.  *Real  Infinite  Series*. Classroom Resource Materials. The Mathematical Association of America, $2006$. isbn: $0883857456$.

The problem above is here: [P.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dWQw.jpg), [P.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQZpj.jpg).

The book did give a proof to the statement at beginning, as a lemma to that problem in the book.

The book said (I use $q$ instead of $e$ in the book) "$\frac{n}{b}<m\le m(b-a)<\frac{n}{a^{q-1}}$ implies a contradiction", but how? And, how to prove $m(b-a)<\frac{n}{a^{q-1}}$?

What I have thought:

If $a^{q-1}\in\mathbb Z$ again and $q-1>1$, then there may be a contradiction since there are just finite many integer between $a$ and $b$, (similar to proof by infinite descent). But well... I think I thought too much. It just doesn't work.

And I back to the problem itself and try, if $a<b$ are natural numbers satisfying the inequality,
\begin{align*}
    0<(za-1)a^{q-1}&<(zb-1)b^{q-1}<1\\
    0<(ma-n)a^{q-1}&<(mb-n)b^{q-1}<n\\
    0<ma^q-na^{q-1}&<mb^q-nb^{q-1}<n\\
    n(b^{q-1}-a^{q-1})&<m(b^q-a^q)\\
    z&>\frac{b^{q-1}-a^{q-1}}{b^q-a^q}
\end{align*}
But it doesn't seem to be constructive.

I would like a proof to the statement at beginning. New proofs are good, in case there are, but I would like, if possible, someone telling me how the arguments in the book flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the inequality
$$0 < (za-1)a^{q-1}$$
holds, then, since $a^{q-1} > 0$, we must have $za = \frac{m}{n}a > 1$, or equivalently
$$m > \frac{n}{a}\,.$$
If $a < b$ are two integers, then $b-a \geqslant 1$, whence $m \leqslant m(b-a)$. If $0 < a < b$ are integer solutions of
$$0 < (zx-1)x^{q-1} < 1\,, \tag{$\ast$}$$
then, since the middle expression in $(\ast)$ is monotonic in $x$ for $x > z^{-1}$, we have
$$0 < (zb-1)b^{q-1} - (za-1)a^{q-1} < 1\,.$$
Since $b^{q-1} > a^{q-1}$ and $zb > za$, it follows that
$$0 < \bigl((zb-1) - (za-1)\bigr)a^{q-1} = \frac{m}{n}(b-a)a^{q-1} \leqslant (zb-1)b^{q-1} - (za-1)a^{q-1} < 1\,,$$
and from that we obtain
$$m(b-a) < \frac{n}{a^{q-1}}\,.$$
But from
$$m < \frac{n}{a^{q-1}}$$
it follows that
$$za = \frac{m}{n}a < \frac{1}{a^{q-2}} \leqslant 1\,,$$
which shows that $a$ can't be a solution of $(\ast)$ by the remark at the top.